# How did Newt graduate from Hogwarts if he got expelled?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, jk-rowling, continuity, fantastic-beasts

JK Rowling revealed<sup>1</sup> on twitter that Newt Scamander got expelled from Hogwarts.

> **J.K. Rowling**
>   @JK_Rowling
>   Dumbledore was a young teacher at the time **Newt was expelled**. He wasn't able to revoke expulsions.
>   ([Source](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/719550328828522496))

Yet we know from *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*<sup>2</sup> that Newt had graduated Hogwarts:

> Upon graduation from Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, Mr. Scamander joined the Ministry of Magic in the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures.
>   <sub>(*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - About the Author*)</sub>

There really should be no way to miss that fact considering how J.K. Rowling's lawyer has said (under oath) that this is a small book.

> For example, the evidence will show that there are 274 entries in the Lexicon pulled from Ms. Rowling's 64-page Quidditch Through The Ages book. I'm holding it up, your Honor. It is not a very big book and they have 274 entries about it alone. Similarly, in her 63-page book, Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them, there are 222 Lexicon entries pulled from this book.
>   <sub>([Warner Bros. vs RDR Books, Day 1, Opening - Ms. Cendali](https://web.archive.org/web/20110721204007/http://cyberlaw.stanford.edu/system/files/Trial+Transcript+Day+1.txt))</sub>

### How did Newt Scamander graduate from Hogwarts if he got expelled?

---

<sup>1</sup>  In as much that the movie isn't a reliable canon source.
<sup>2</sup> The book, not the movie. (Nothing about this question concerns the movie.)

Comment: We should consider the possibility that he was expelled and *then* returned to finish his degree, once he had deeds to his name.

Comment: @Jonah - Which is supported by the fact that Hermione returned to finish her degree, establishing an (out-of-universe) precedent.

Comment: Perhaps the later films are about his Hogwarts redemption?

Comment: Oh. Do we know in which year he was expelled ? Maybe he passed his OWLs but was expelled in his 6th or 7th year, so he technically has a Hogwarts degree.

Comment: @ibid How is that out of universe?

Comment: @Acccumulation I presume because it is something JKRowling has said rather than written.

Comment: @Acccumulation - It would be a precedent for J.K. Rowling to say that Newt did the same, hence out-of-universe. Hermione cannot set an in-universe precedent for Newt because if this is true Newt would have been the one to have done it first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tie-in book [**The Case of Beasts: Explore the Film Wizardry of Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MYMC20B) contains the following article which relates to Newt's supposed crimes.

A [closer inspection](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/8/8e/Newt%27s_Explusion.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20161203041952) reveals that Newt was indeed formally expelled, but that his expulsion was never "enforced" (whatever that means). This presumably includes allowing him to graduate *and* to keep his wand.

> **NOTES:** *Proposed expulsion from Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry due to the illegal possession of a magical beast causing
>   endangerment of human life and violation of animal welfare laws
>   101/304.*
>
> **Magical Beast:** *Jarvey, Level 3*
>
> **Punishment:** *Expulsion from Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.*
>
> - ***The expulsion was never enforced - Hogwarts Professor Albus Dumbledore defended Newton resulting in his name being cleared.***
>
> *The Ministry of Magic Animal Welfare Department were also informed of the violation and required to rehouse the magical creature.*

[image]

Comment: I consider Rowling's Twitter to be higher Canon than movie tie-in books, but still, this more directly answers the question.

Comment: @ibid - Yeah, it's an odd addition and one I didn't expect to find. I wonder if it'll get contradicted or whether this document wasn't meant to be readable.

Answer (score 10):

This is probably just a case of Rowling retconing a minor fact where she felt it would improve the story. 
It remains to be seen if the upcoming "expanded edition" of Fantastic Beasts will change that line.

Some possible in-universe answers:

- He returned later to finish his degree.

  While this is possible, the only precedent is Hermione, who definitely wasn't expelled. Dumbledore supporting Newt wouldn't have helped much, seeing as he had only recently started teaching there. As [JKR says](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/719550328828522496),

  > **@Potterish**: @jk_rowling but we also know that Dumbledore has come to defend him. So, was the expulsion revoked? :)
  >   **@JK_Rowling**: Dumbledore was a young teacher at the time Newt was expelled. He wasn't able to revoke expulsions.

  It's possible that he only went back after redeeming himself through the publication of Fantastic Beasts, and the graduation fact was added in later editions.
- It was an error that Obscurus books never picked up apon, even though the book is in it's fifty-second edition.

  > Mr. Scamander’s work  with the Dragon Research and Restraint Bureau led to  many research  trips  abroad, during which he collected information for his worldwide best-seller  Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them,  now in  its fifty-second edition.
- Obscurus books blurred the truth for political reasons or to better sell the book.
- He was expelled in his sixth or seventh year, after having already received his O.W.L.s.

  While we don't know this to be true, it's possible that would be enough to be deemed "graduating", at least for someone trying to laud praises in an about the Sirius the author blurb. (Also, with his name, why even bother taking the N.E.W.T.s? )

<sub>Lots of these ideas were inspired by comments from Jonah, ThruGog, and Pwassonne.</sub>

Comment: A quick google didn't help - but when u say expanded edition of FBaWtFT do you mean a new edition of the book? (doesn't affect Question, I'm just curious. Got a link?) :)

Comment: @MacCooper - [Here](https://www.pottermore.com/news/ww-publishing-cursed-child-script-book-announcement) and [here](http://blog.theblairpartnership.com), and later, over [here](http://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/superpage/fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them/) as well. Possibly more places since.

Comment: fantastic! Ta :)

Comment: I self-answered because there is an upvoted answer that I disagree with.

Comment: Lol. Imagine turning up at your NEWT exam and the examiner being like "Name?". Scamander would go "Newt, now give me an O".

Answer (score 10):

### This has been retconned in later editions to remove mention of Newt graduating Hogwarts

[image]

> **2001 Edition:** Upon **graduation from** Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, Mr. Scamander joined the Ministry of Magic in the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures.
>
> **2017 Edition:** Upon **leaving** Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, Mr. Scamander joined the Ministry of Magic in the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing to say you can't go back. Hermione went back after going to hunt horcruxes with Harry.

> **JKR:** Harry and Ron didn't go back. Hermione did.
>
> **SU:** (gasps) Ooo!
>
> **MA:** Oh my-
>
> **JKR:** Did you bet right? I mean, come on, nobody's going to think
>   Hermione wouldn't go back.
>
> **SU:** I predicted. Yeah.
>
> <sub>- *JKR Interview with Leaky Cauldron - 2007*</sub>

Furthermore, Hagrid was expelled and became a teacher.

And we all know rules can change, like how Harry got a broomstick and became the youngest seeker in a century.

> "That's a broomstick," he said, throwing it back to Harry with a mixture of jealousy and spite on his face. "You'll be in for it this time, Potter, first years aren't allowed them." 
>   <sub>- *Philosopher's Stone*</sub>

Anything is possible in Hogwarts, especially under Dumbledores rule because we know he just didn't care and yolo'd everything xD

Comment: Hermione was never expelled, though—she just took a ‘gap year’ (of sorts), and given the rather unusual circumstances, nobody in their right mind—except Death Eaters, if you count them as being in their right mind—would begrudge her that ‘gap year’. I don't think there's any actual canon precedence for being expelled and then allowed to return, but since it can happen in real-world Muggle schools, I don't see why it couldn't possibly happen at Hogwarts too.

Comment: This wasn't under Dumbledore's rule.

Comment: I mean, Hermione was _sort of_ expelled for a year, thanks to a policy from the new management.  I heard they peacefully recanted on said policy the following year though.

Comment: *Dumbledore was a young teacher at the time Newt was expelled. He wasn't able to revoke expulsions.* ([Source](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/719550328828522496))

Comment: @ibid okay, last point confirmed as not likely. But possibly Dippet? I'm not too sure about the timelines but it would be cool to have a year by year comparison of Hogwarts events with Scamander events as well, if you know of one?

Comment: @user3564421 - [This](http://i.imgur.com/K3k2leR.png?1) and [this](http://i.imgur.com/Y6WLm0I.png?1).

Comment: @ibid oh wow that's really useful. thanks dude!

Comment: @user3564421 - The info mainly came from the lexicon's [secret new site](https://beta.hp-lexicon.org), (which hasn't yet implemented it's timeline.)

Comment: @ibid how secret new site xD

Comment: @ibid ah it looks pretty cool. anything I can do to help (proofread? etc) let me know.